# Less CSS - How to do IE filters with less variable inside?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, escaping, less

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LessCSS - IE gradient filter with variables and lighten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324729/lesscss-ie-gradient-filter-with-variables-and-lighten)

How do i embed variables in this property?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 )";
```

I tried escaping it and concatinating the variables with + signs, like this:

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='" + @from + "', endColorstr='" + @to + "',GradientType=0 )";
```

No success.

The doc has an example of IE filters where they escape the string, but they didn't embed a variable inside.

Any ideas?